# Exercise 4.4.1 Terence Tao

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I am self-studying Terence Tao. I am stuck on the following question.

Exercise 4.4.1. Let $x$ be a rational number. Then there exists an integer n such that $n \leq x x < n + 1$. In fact, this integer is unique. I solved the uniqueness part.

For existence I have the following starting point. I am stuck though. let $x = \frac{p}{q}$.
By Euclidean algorithm there exists c and s such that $x = ps + c$ where $0 \leq c < s$.

I am not sure what to do after that.

Comment: What do you mean "studying T. T."  Are you studying one (or all) of his textbooks?

Comment: Does setting $n = \lfloor xx \rfloor$ not work?

Comment: @ChubbyChef we are trying to prove that.

Comment: One hint is given is using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @mjw all of his books. Though in particular this case I am solving Terence Tao Volume 1.

Comment: @joeblacksmith You should use Chubby Chef's suggestion. You get one inequality immediately and the other case is almost as immediate.

Comment: @JohnDouma we don't know that ⌊⌋ exist we are trying to prove that.

Comment: Is $xx$ a typo, are we referring to $x^2$, or does Tao assign some other meaning to that symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $xx = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q \in \mathbb{Z} > 0$. By the Euclidean algorithm, we can write $p = nq + s$ where $0 \leq s < q$. Hence
$$nq \leq p < (n + 1)q.$$
This means $n \leq \frac{p}{q} < n + 1$.

Comment: Yes, this is the argument I had similar to above though wasn't able to write it down. Thank you.